# Running my first RSpec test, is there any way to print just the error with no backtrace?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm looking at this tutorial online:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted

```
# game_spec.rb
describe Game do
  describe "#score" do
    it "returns 0 for all gutter game" do
      game = Game.new
      20.times { game.roll(0) }
      game.score.should == 0
   end
 end
end
```

Running the first example, I noticed that the error message they list is much shorter than what I'm seeing. On my terminal the stack trace is so long it scrolls off the top. Is there any way to shorter error message / stack output to make this fit?

```
/testspec/game_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Game (NameError)
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I stripped my home dir from the list of dirs there. Is it possible to order verbosity down to simply the NameError line?

Comment: It would help if you could show us the output (errors). I guess you problem in your configuration/installation.

Comment: Sure. I posted them above since the comment box is a bit too small.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed in the comment, there is an error with your configuration/installation.

```
`require': cannot load such file -- ./game
```

Ruby can not find that file. Make sure you have the correct file in place, and run the test again.

Comment: Ah sorry, I modified my files to get that output result. The code listing above has a different result. Editing!

Comment: Right, so my question stands either way, is there a way to limit the output to the first Error?